# css animation to mimic the matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the Matrix, the characters didn't seem to be alphabetical, but my boss wants me to have a matrix of item numbers going down the screen as they are being ordered.  That way he can sit there and watch.

Has css evolved enough to accomodate this? I can specify that he use Google Chrome to watch the traffic go by. :)

I need a way to have an Item number (example: 1007-24) slide down the screen ala Matrix style.  It should look like this:

```
1
0
0
7
-
2
4
```

Then what I'll do is have a bunch of items scrolling down the screen at random y positions at random speeds.  I suppose to be fancy I could worry about changing the dash to a pipe, but that's just an idiosyncrasy of this particular example.

Let me see how it would look the other way:

```
4
2
-
7
0
0
1
```

Hmmm.. I don't know which way would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel when it's already out there for you:

- http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/matrix-rain-animation-html5-canvas-javascript
- http://cssdeck.com/labs/the-matrix
- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex10/matrixeffect.htm

Ah. Here's a pure CSS solution courtesy of [http://girliemac.com/blog/2009/05/03/matrix-animation-with-webkit-css3/](https://web.archive.org/web/20110807080625/http://girliemac.com/sandbox/matrix.html)

I've extracted it and have it working on jsfiddle. Doesn't look pretty there, but I'm certain a browser will render it a great deal better`.`

http://jsfiddle.net/mSK9P/1/